# R can't connect to Spigot server using ropenscilabs miner package

Tags: r, networking, server, minecraft, ropensci

I would like to try out the [miner](https://github.com/ropenscilabs/miner) Minecraft API from ROpenSci and am having trouble connecting to the server from R. I am sure this is a networking issue rather than a R or Minecraft issue but I don't really have any experience in this area.

I have followed the vignette and installed [spigot](https://www.spigotmc.org/) on my Arch machine following [these instructions](https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-spigot-server-on-arch-linux) and can successfully start the server and connect to it using the Minecraft client.

However when I try to connect through R I am unable to do so. This is what I get:

```
 library(miner)
 mc_connect("127.0.0.1")
Error in socketConnection(host = hostname, as.integer(port), open = "r+b",  : 
   cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
   In socketConnection(host = hostname, as.integer(port), open = "r+b",  :
   127.0.0.1:4711 cannot be opened
```

I also tried "localhost" and adding server-ip=127.0.0.1

This looks like fun so it would be cool to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is my server.properties file if it helps:

````
#Minecraft server properties
#Wed Jul 12 21:30:47 NZST 2017
generator-settings=
force-gamemode=true
allow-nether=true
gamemode=1
enable-query=false
player-idle-timeout=0
difficulty=0
spawn-monsters=true
op-permission-level=4
pvp=true
snooper-enabled=true
level-type=DEFAULT
hardcore=false
enable-command-block=false
max-players=20
network-compression-threshold=256
resource-pack-sha1=
max-world-size=29999984
server-port=25565
debug=false
server-ip=
spawn-npcs=true
allow-flight=false
level-name=world
view-distance=10
resource-pack=
spawn-animals=true
white-list=false
generate-structures=true
online-mode=true
max-build-height=256
level-seed=
prevent-proxy-connections=false
use-native-transport=true
enable-rcon=false
motd=My very own minecraft server```
````